# Can I implement the following conditional media query using styled components in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to add a `wrapper` class to a styled component in React. Is there any that I can implement it so that the CSS is generated as follows?

```
.test-class {
    color: red;
    font-size: 40px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .wrapper .test-class { 
       color: blue;
       font-size: 30px;
    }
}
```

Something like this

```
const Content = styled.div`
    color: red;
    font-size: 40px;

    @media (max-width: 600px) {
       .wrapper {
            color: blue;
            font-size: 30px;
       }
    } 
`;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample template to do so

```js
const Content = styled.div`
  background: papayawhip;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;

  @media (max-width: 700px) {
    background: palevioletred;
  }
`;

render(
  <Content />
);
```

For more information refer - https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced

Comment: Thanks  but I believe the CSS generated in this case will be

```
    .some-class-name {
         ...
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        .some-class-name {
              background: palevioletred;
        }
    }
```

What I need is to add `.wrapper` before `.some-class-name` inside the media query

Answer (score 0):

You can create media query file or/and add this following code

```
const size = {
  tablet: '600px',
}
const device = {
  yourSize: `(max-width: ${size.tablet})`,
}
```

And change your styled-component class by using selector for reference your test-class under the wrapper like this

```
const TestClass = styled.div`
  color: red;
  font-size: 40px;
`;
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  @media ${device.yourSize}  {  
    ${TestClass} {
      color: blue;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
  }
`;

 render(
  <Wrapper>
    <TestClass>Text</TestClass>
  </Wrapper>
 );
```